# How to change the message in woocommerce order table

Tags: wordpress, hook-woocommerce

This is my first post here and I am really hoping that someone will be able to assist..

I am using woocommerce 2.6 and when the product is in stock (for example invetory of 2) and I make the backorder choice “Allow, but notify customer”, then on the product page I can see 'in stock'.
Then, the notifications displayed in the cart, checkout and subsequent customer emails is showing 'Back ordered: 4'
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZdVL.png)

Could you please tell me how I can change the message 'Back ordered: 4' to 'Low Stock'?

I tried to search for the string 'Back ordered' using grep -r "Back ordered" but couldn't find it anywherestrong text

Could anyone please help?
Thank you
Fred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll find it in /includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-order.php

```
wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, apply_filters('woocommerce_backordered_item_meta_name', __( 'Backordered', 'woocommerce' ) ), $qty - max( 0, $product->get_total_stock() ) );
```

And you can also change it in the language file, it is the proper way to do it.

Comment: I replace [code]wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, apply_filters('woocommerce_backordered_item_meta_name', __( 'Backordered', 'woocommerce' ) ), $qty - max( 0, $product->get_total_stock() ) );[/code]with [code]wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, apply_filters('woocommerce_backordered_item_meta_name', __( 'Low stock', 'woocommerce' ) ), $qty - max( 0, $product->get_total_stock() ) );[/code] and it work perfectly thank you:) now, how do I make sure that the code is not ovewritten on woocemmerce update?

Comment: You should copy the file into your theme folder wp-content/themes/YourTheme/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-order.php

Comment: Hi, 
I replace <code>wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, apply_filters('woocommerce_backordered_item_meta_name', __( 'Backordered', 'woocommerce' ) ), $qty - max( 0, $product->get_total_stock() ) );</code>with <code>wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, apply_filters('woocommerce_backordered_item_meta_name', __( 'Low stock', 'woocommerce' ) ), $qty - max( 0, $product->get_total_stock() ) );</code> and it work perfectly thank you:) now, how do I make sure that the code is not ovewritten on woocemmerce update?

Comment: Sorry for the above, i'm new here...How do yiu out code in stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0):

This message is located here : 
wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-formatting-functions.php

```
$display .= ' ' ;// . __( '(can be backordered)', 'woocommerce' );
```